# Laptop speaker sound significantly worse than Windows

Tags: sound, firefox, pulseaudio, alsa

I've been using Ubuntu since the last few days and the only Problem which I have left is that the sound from my Laptop speakers (L380 Yoga) is worse than on my Windows 10 installation.

1. The sound on Firefox (e.g. when I'm on YouTube) is always set on 80% ([see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3n4G.jpg) screenshot) even when I change it to 100%, once I close Firefox or just change the song/video, it gets reset to 80%.
2. My speakers have less bass. I think I can fix that with an equalizer.

Comment: Some devices are indeed better supported in Windows due to proprietary drivers and bundled software. Lenovo does that a lot and your laptop has support for Windows only from the manufacturer. There may not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Actually I checked on reddit. There are some solutions. I'm going to allow audio up to 150% and change either the pulseaudio config or use an equalizer. However, my question is that the audio bar, doesn't show audio above 100%. And that I need to manually increase firefox to play at 100%

Comment: There's a setting to enable "over 100%"